# Hide a base class from a dll

Tags: c#

I have a `BaseClass` which is inherited by about 20+ classes in an assembly. The properties of this base class are used by some other assembly (friend assembly). I have declared the properties as `internal` so that no other assembly sees or uses them.

Now, is there a way to also hide the `BaseClass` itself from the other assemblies except the friend assembly? Some better mechanism or design construct perhaps?

I cannot make the `BaseClass` `internal` since the classes which inherit it are `public`.

This is how the `BaseClass` looks like at the moment.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyApp.FriendAssembly1")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyApp.FriendAssembly2")]
namespace MyApp.Input
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Note: The members of this class are visible only to certain friend assemblies. The normal consumers of this assembly can simply ignore this class.
    /// </summary>
    public class BaseClass
    {

        internal bool Property1 { get; set; }

        internal bool Property2 { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's not possible. Period.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Every class in the inheritance tree has to have at least the same visibility as the deriving class.

I wonder why this is important to you. If it is just because you don't want others to be able to inherit it, create an internal constructor.

Comment: No, it isn't that I want to disable inheritance, it is just that others shouldn't know that such a base class exists. The reason for the existence of this class is to avoid having those internal properties in all the other 20+ classes and having the friend assembly attribute on all of them.

Comment: As said, that isn't possible

Comment: I want to note it is allowed to derive from an internal interface. Not sure if that is in any way helpful to you.

Comment: Not if you in implement them explicitly.

Comment: Could you provide an example in your answer?

Comment: Yes. But not now. I will later this day.

Comment: can you please provide the example?